# Can I connect to an https websocket with python?

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, socket.io

I've been using python to connect to `ws://` websocket streams with great success using [websocket-client](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client/0.7.0). However, when I try to connect to an `https://`-schemed stream, the library complains about `https` not being supported. [This](https://bitfloor.com/docs/api/market-data/websocket#book) page seems to suggest that it's possible to connect to such a stream via https using socket.io in javascript.

I'm not a javascript master, so there might be some subtlety I'm missing here, but can this be done in python?

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to connect from or to Python using SSL?

Comment: I'm confused what javascript has to do with all of this. It sounds like you're trying to use python, so a javascript solution isn't what you want (unless you want to switch all your code over to javascript).

Comment: Of course it's possible to have a Python client talk WSS to a WebSocket server. Whether the specific library you use does support this I don't know. A library that includes a WebSocket client that speaks WSS is AutobahnPython (Disclaimer: I am the author of Autobahn). Note that in any case the scheme to use is "wss" not "https".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I was confusing websockets, which are implemented with a standard protocol, and socket.io sockets, which seem to implement a handshake between the server and the client to iron out browser incompatibilities.

Python has a good websockets implementation, but doesn't seem to have a good socket.io socket implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The secure [URI scheme for websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#URI_scheme) is `wss://`

Try to connect using `wss://` instead of `https://`

Comment: I get an exception from the SSL C library: `SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown proto`

Comment: @Alex Check your server supports `wss`

Answer (score -3):

In python you can use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) to connect to https urls. For instance you could do the following:

```
import urllib2

conn = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.google.com/")
content = conn.read()
print(content)
```

Comment: you cannot connect to websocket using urlopen